# Session scoped property in an entity JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm very new to JPA. My question is : Is it possible to have a property define in an entity that is not persisted in database but is SessionScoped ?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article_v_m")
public class Article implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "cart")
    private String ref;

    @Transient
    public static final List<String> STATUS_PUBLISHED = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("", "D", "R"));

    @Transient
    public static final List<String> STATUS_DEAD = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("M", "E", "V"));

    @Transient
    public static final List<String> STATUS_UPCOMING = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("A"));

    // I want this property to be SessionScoped
    // The problem is that it persists between sessions
    // I know this is because of the @Transient annotation
    @Transient
    public Double realDiscountPercent = 0.00;

    @Column(name = "isbn")
    private String isbn;

    @Column(name = "lart")
    private String title;

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        if (fullTitle == null || fullTitle.isEmpty()) {
        return title;
    }
        return fullTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Double getRealDiscountPercent() {
        return realDiscountPercent;
    }

    public void setRealDiscountPercent(Double realDiscountPercent) {
        this.realDiscountPercent = realDiscountPercent;
    }
}
```

The aim is to retrieve realDiscountPercent between views, but reset it when the session is closed. I calculate it in the market view, and want to get this information in the caddy view. Right now, this value remains the same even if I disconnect and connect back with another account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a property to be session scoped it needs to be a `singleton` bean so you can create one like:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class MyStringProvider implements Provider<String> {

   private String value = "something";

   public String get() {
       return this.value;
   }
}
```

then you can access it like:

```
@Autowired
private Provider<String> myStringProvider;
```

...

```
System.out.println(myStringProvider.get());
```